# How do I send an embed with buttons to a specific channel in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to send an embed to a specific channel (`1068005047373414481`) and I'd like to send an embed with the sort of new buttons using the `ActionRow` components. Keep in mind that the channel is not the same channel where the interaction will be ran. Anyways I've tried using the `interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(id).send(embed);` method but it seems to not work. I always end up getting a `DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message` error. Either way I don't think you can add components to that message like you can do with `interaction.reply({ embeds: embed, components: [row] });`

Here is my current code:

```js
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!')
    client.user.setActivity("all you rascals", {
        type: ActivityType.Watching,
    });
    var testing = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('test')

    client.guilds.cache.get(guild).channels.cache.get(channel).send(testing)
})
```

(This is for testing as I will implement the correct way into my bot once I find an answer)

When I run that I get this error:

```
C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\a\c\fbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293
        throw new DiscordAPIError.DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
              ^

DiscordAPIError[50006]: Cannot send an empty message
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\a\c\fbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:293:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\a\c\fbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.cjs:99:14)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\a\c\fbot\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\REST.cjs:52:22)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\a\c\fbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:175:15) {
  rawError: { message: 'Cannot send an empty message', code: 50006 },
  code: 50006,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/1068005047373414481/messages',
  requestBody: {
    files: [],
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
interaction.reply({ embeds: embed, components: [row] });
```

Is very close to what you need, remember that the embeds property must be an array of embeds, even if you only have one.

The correct code would be

```js
interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], components: [row] });
```